# Saving RTF on DataBase and loading it back into WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows Forms Application with a RichTextBox control. I want the user to write rich text on that control (with bold, changes of letter size and all that stuff), save that rich text on database, and then load it again on my Windows Forms application properly formatted.

The way I'm trying to do this, I save on a varchar field in my database the contain of RichTextBox.Rtf property, like this:

```
string richText = myRichTextBox.Rtf;
```

Then richText is saved on database exactly as is read on that line. To load the rich text back into winform, code is a little bit more tricky:

```
//Function that receives a string whit rich text and loads it into richTextBox
private void LoadRTF(string RTF)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(RTF));
    myRichTextBox.LoadFile(stream, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
} //LoadRTF
```

Problem is with this last code, when loading RTF from database is throwing an argument exception. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ASCII encoding? Try UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just not escaping some characters in SQL query. Now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: We never had a chance to figure that out from the question. A [mcve] would have helped here.